# Drawing on to a programmatically created Panel in a C# WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, mouseevent

I've got a bunch of questions with certain answer types in my database. I currently use them for questionnaires on an android app, but I'd like to also view them on a desktop application so you can get a rough idea of what it'll look like and to make it easier to add questions and stuff. Buuuuuuut! Adding things programmatically in a C# form seems to be more effort than in android. I've got all the basic ones down(texbox, checkbox, dropdown) but I'm trying to do a drawing one now.

I figured I'd use a Panel since I can draw on it, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've just been browsing and googling what to do in terms of this since I'm not terribly well acquainted with C# Forms. I set a `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` event handler and on the `MouseMove` event handler, I try draw it and the code gets called and it executes the line but nothing happens. It's either something really smaller and silly or I'm going about it in a wrong way. If I can't do it that way, I don't mind any other suggestions as to how I'd do it. It's all done dynamically, so it adds question + answer type to a `TableLayoutPanel`, so it'd need to be addable to that. As far as I'm aware, a Canvas isn't a Control, so I can't add it.

This is the relevant code:

```
switch (questionnaireAnswerType.questionnaireAnswerTypeId)
                {
                    case 1:
                        ComboBox dropDown = new ComboBox();
                        dropDown.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
                        String[] items = question.dropDownContents.Split(';');
                        dropDown.Items.AddRange(items);
                        tablePanel.Controls.Add(dropDown, 1, index);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                        textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
                        tablePanel.Controls.Add(textBox, 1, index);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                        checkBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
                        tablePanel.Controls.Add(checkBox, 1, index);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Panel drawPanel = new Panel();
                        System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size();
                        drawPanel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(drawPanel_MouseDown);
                        drawPanel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(drawPanel_MouseMove);
                        size.Height = 100;
                        size.Width = 500;
                        drawPanel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                        drawPanel.Size = size;
                        AddTableRow();
                        tablePanel.Controls.Add(drawPanel, 0, index +1);
                        tablePanel.SetColumnSpan(drawPanel, 2);
                        break;
                }
```

And these are the mousedown events:

```
 void drawPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Line line = new Line();

            line.Stroke = System.Windows.SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
            line.X2 = e.Location.X;
            line.Y2 = e.Location.Y;

            currentPoint = e.Location;

            using (Graphics g = ((Panel) sender).CreateGraphics())
            {
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), new System.Drawing.Point(currentPoint.X, currentPoint.Y), new System.Drawing.Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y));
            }
        }
    }

    void drawPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            currentPoint = e.Location;
    }
```

Comment: In your MouseMove method, get rid of `currentPoint = e.Location;` or move it to *after* your draw code.  Using CreateGraphics is almost always wrong.  Use the Panel's paint event and call `drawPanel.Invalidate();` to have the panel call it's paint routine.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I moved it to after, but that didn't really do anything. How do I access the panel's graphics then? Don't forget I've not got the panel referenced globally, since it's added dynamically. I added a Paint eventhandler and invalidated the sender but that just made it handle weird especially when scrolling the ParentPanel.

Comment: Same way you wired the MouseMove event.  PaintEventArgs will have a Graphic object you use for drawing.

Comment: But it won't know what to draw, will it? If I have the points inside MouseMove event, then how will the Paint Event method have knowledge of them?

Comment: You will need another variable to tell you the end point.  Or a list of points if there are many.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'd store them and be able to fetch them, though. Is it possible to have an inner method so I simply have to declare the variables I'm using as final, but still able to use them in the event handler? Essentially how android does it.

Comment: I don't know what Android does, and I don't know what your program is trying to do.  The variables would have to be declared at the form level, like you did for currentPoint.

Comment: Did it and didn't like that very much. It manages to draw somewhat. It'll only show if you scroll back and forth, though. And even then, it won't have drawn properly. Are there any other suggestions you can make instead of using a Panel to draw on? Perhaps something that's drawable via mouse clicks already?

Comment: You have to update your post with your changes.  I can't see your code.

Comment: They're not particularly relevant. Like I said, I don't think it's going to work if I have external events, so I'd like to have a Canvas that has its own event handlers without me having to add any. If there's not one currently, then I'll probably just end up making my own.

Comment: Regarding this: `Adding things programmatically in a C# form seems to be more effort than in android` - that's because you're using obsolete, irrelevant technology. Sure, if you try to do all this with a thing like COBOL you're going to have a hard time. Forget useless winforms and focus on current technologies instead. XAML-based technologies are going to be more familiar to you if you come from an Android background, due to the XML-based UI style rather than the horrible winforms procedural code approach. Additionally, XAML enables DataBinding, which makes things even easier for dynamic UIs.

Comment: Reading up on WPF and XAML, they do seem very easy and familiar to what I'm used to. Unfortunately, though, I'm simply adding on what another developer's already done and it'd be too much effort to rewrite in WPF or change it over.